# Crush when turn off the gps

Tags: android, geolocation

I receive crush, when user turn off the gps.
I have code like this to detect location`s user

```
if(locationManager == null) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L,
                15f, mLocationListener);
    } else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000L,
                15f, mLocationListener);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on gps on ypur phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

When user open app with gps, then turn off it, I receive crush like this

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.location.LocationListener.onProviderDisabled(java.lang.String)"
```

I tried to detect when user turn off gps, but I get crush earlier, then receiver detect

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener#onProviderDisabled(java.lang.String) says it has a default implementation, but you should  override onProviderDisabled to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Find the declaration of mLocationListerner. Surely it overrite `onLocationChanged()`. But you may have forgotten override `onProviderDisabled()`. Do it even if it's empty. Override also `onStatusChanged()` and `onProviderEnabled()`.

Luck.

```
LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      ....
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

};
```